# Convert Date String Mon Mar 30 13:51:35 UTC 2015 to Date Object

Tags: java, date, datetime, simpledateformat

I am trying to convert a string such as

```
String dateString = "Mon Mar 30 13:51:35 UTC 2015";
```

in a Date Object.

I tried this:

```
DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss ZZZ yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
    sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    System.out.println("Date Object:"+sdf.parse(dateString));
```

But the output of the date object is

```
Mon Mar 30 15:51:35 CEST 2015
```

as you can see:
1) it forwards the string's time ahead to two hours
2) it changes UTC --> CEST

I tried many solutions, but nothing worked. What is the correct way to do this?

EDIT: my objective here is to have a Date object from that original String. That Date Object should have the same parameters as the date string. In this case, the original hours of day (13) is turned to 15, but the desired is for it to stay at 13. I need this because in my program I will need to compare two different date objects.

EDIT: JAVA 8 SOLUTION
Searching the more recent Java 8, I found a better and more elegant solution. Here is the code

```
 String pattern = "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss SSS zzz yyyy"; 
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(pattern, Locale.UK).withZone(ZoneId.of("UTC"));
final ZonedDateTime parsed = ZonedDateTime.parse(dateString, formatter);
```

Furthermore, to compare it with, for example, the current time:

```
 ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.now();

        int compared = parsed.compareTo(now);

        System.out.println("NOW:"+now.toLocalDateTime()+" PARSED:"+parsed.toLocalDateTime()+" COMPARED:"+compared);
```

Comment: Where are you located? That seems like the same date to me.

Comment: Remember that a date doesn't have a format.

Comment: I don't think you understand that a date is a timestamp. It's a snapshot of whatever time it was at a give moment. It's the same time now where I am in California as it is where you are in CEST (or wherever). If I created `Date` object here and you created one there, they'd still represent the same time and be `equals` to one another.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing it correctly. The date is being parsed correctly. You are just printing the date into your local computer timezone. When you do toString() to a date, prints the date in your local machine timezone.

Mon Mar 30 15:51:35 CEST 2015 == Mon Mar 30 13:51:35 UTC 2015

CEST is UTC +2

Answer (score 0):

A `java.util.Date` does not have a time zone, practically speaking. There is a time zone inside but it cannot be set nor gotten. One of many poor design decisions made in these old date-time classes.

The `Date::toString` method applies your JVM’s current default time zone when generating the output string. Done with good intentions, but not helpful as it creates the illusion your Date object is in that zone when in fact it is not.

## java.time

You are using a troublesome old legacy class, now supplanted by the java.time framework built into Java 8 and later.

Convert from a `Date` to an `Instant`, a moment on the timeline in UTC with a resolution of nanoseconds.

```
Instant instant = myJavaUtilDate.toInstant();
```

Call `toString`. The java.time classes use standard ISO 8601 formats when parsing/generating strings.

```
String output = instant.toString();
```

To create strings, convert from `Instant` to `OffsetDateTime` using the constant `ZoneOffset.UTC`. Then work with the java.time.format classes to generate the string.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.ofInstant( instant , ZoneOffset.UTC );
```

Search Stack Overflow for more info and examples. These issues have  addressed hundreds of times already.

Comment: Thank you ver much. I should've looked for a more mordern way to do it, and the project is also developed with a jdk 8.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of `UTC`, use `GMT` when getting the timezone.

```
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
```

[Source](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html)

Answer (score -1):

You already have the `Date` object. If you want to print it in format you want, you can use `DateFormat` to [`format`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#format-java.util.Date-) the `Date` object as well:

```
Date date = sdf.parse(dateString);
System.out.println("Date Object:"+sdf.format(date));
// Use the date object ...
```

Comment: Although, sure, this will print what they want, it is completely pointless.  Just print the `dateString` directly. `sdf.format(sdf.parse(whatever))` is more or less a no-op.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis You're right, but the idea is to show the method he might be looking for.

Comment: Why would they be looking for a no-op?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I think he's looking for a method that gives a string he wants. That's all the point of the answer. Anyway, I edited the answer. I hope it's clearer now.

Comment: Thank you for the replies. I have to compare the date string from an xml  with other dates taken somewhere else. The string printing at the end was simply to see what the Date object was like. I actually need a Date Object from that original string. That is why I need the HH:mm:ss to be exactly they way it was originally (aka it was 13 hrs in String and it is desired to be 13 hrs in Date object also)